# Materialize autocomplete drop-down not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, materialize

I have been working with materialize autocomplete for my project and I have been running into issues with getting the dropdown to appear. It just fails to appear! I read that materialize version 0.98.2 might work, I used that CDN and it still doesn't work. I suspect there is some problem with triggering the dropdown. (I could be very wrong) another thing that could be wrong is that the data isn't being used because I messed up somewhere.

I am having no problem getting the data and using that, but the dropdown just wnt work.

html:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="country">Autocomplete</label>
    <input type="text" id="company" class="autocomplete">
</div>
```

here is my js:

```
var company = document.getElementById("company");

  company.addEventListener("input", function () {
      $(function() {
      var inputValue = $('#company').val();
      var url = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/'
              + encodeURIComponent(inputValue)
              + '/?token=****************';
      
       $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
          
          var companyArray = response;
          var dataCompany = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < companyArray.length; i++) {
            //console.log(countryArray[i].name);
            console.log(url);
            dataCompany[companyArray[i].securityName] = companyArray[i].symbol;
            console.log(companyArray[i].securityName);
            console.log(companyArray[i].symbol);
          }
          $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: dataCompany
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Since someone requested the response I am putting some screenshots here!
this is when I enter "wa"

[image]

the problem is not that the data isn't there, it's just that the dropdown selector box fails to appear.

Comment: HI, can you show output of `response` ?

Comment: @Swati umm, I could show you the console logs, but there isn't really much I could show you otherwise since the dropdown doesn't appear so, I can't show it not appearing but I will try my best to add some informational screenshots, also, there really is no error message, it just doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You can first intialize your autocomplete and store instance of that in some variable . Then , whenever user type inside input-box simply use that instance to update data inside your autocomplete i.e : `instance.updateData(dataCompany)` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is response return from ajax
var response = [{
  "securityName": "abc",
  "symbol": "scsc"
}, {
  "securityName": "abc2",
  "symbol": "scsc2"
}]

$(function() {
  $('input#company').autocomplete() //intialize your autocomplete
  let instance = M.Autocomplete.getInstance($('input#company')); //get instance
  $('input.autocomplete').on("input", function() {
    var inputValue = $('#company').val();
    /*var url = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/' +
      encodeURIComponent(inputValue) +
      '/?token=****************';
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      success: function(response) {*/
    var companyArray = response;
    var dataCompany = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < companyArray.length; i++) {
      dataCompany[companyArray[i].securityName] = companyArray[i].symbol;

    }
    //updatedata
    instance.updateData(dataCompany)
    /*  }
    });*/

  });
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-field">
  <label for="country">Autocomplete</label>
  <input type="text" id="company" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: this seems promissing! I will try this out, I think this will work! Thank you for your time!

Comment: it gives the following error, what might I be doing wrong??
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined

Comment: I will add a codepen link, please have a look at my code, I might be doing something wrong, I don't have much experience with JS I work on the backend. 
https://codepen.io/VardhanMahajan/pen/poRLvYO

Comment: yes please use js code which i have added in my answer  and see if that works ..

Comment: thanks it works!!! but I am getting a lot of errors https://imgur.com/zHpumrK

Comment: what is apc-gf ..? and this occur when you click on options ? `companyArray[i].symbol` is symbol and its value is assign to image tag inside autocomplete so its not finding that image that's the reason you are getting 404 error

Comment: apc-gf is the response I get for the symbol. it's scrambled since I am using the sandbox version right now. oh, Okay, I will deal with image 404! Thanks for the help!